# Codeigniter routing is not working with following procedure

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to do routing in code-igniter and i have done the below steps also
but it is not working.I have done all the required settings also but then also
its not working.Please let me know is i am missing any thing or not.

**Step 1**

Add This in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 2:**

Remove index.php in codeigniter config

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Step 3**

Add this in route.php

```
$route['Viewsignup'] = 'Login/index/Viewsignup';
```

My url is like that:
http://localhost/machinetest/index.php/Login/Viewsignup

I want this url:
http://localhost/machinetest/index.php/Viewsignup

Please help me,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `$route['Viewsignup'] = 'Login/index/Viewsignup';` should be `$route['Viewsignup'] = 'Login/Viewsignup';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.htaccess` should not be issue here. Try this

```
$route['Viewsignup'] = 'Login/Viewsignup';
```

This will take you into `Login` controller's `Viewsignup` method when your URL looks like `http://localhost/machinetest/index.php/Viewsignup`

And for removing `index.php` from URL just update your `.htaccess` with following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now `http://localhost/machinetest/Viewsignup` URL will work too

Comment: @varunjoshi So what you see when hit this URL? `http://localhost/machinetest/Viewsignup`

Comment: yes when i directly hits this url it is working fine.I find the problem i call this controller like this  <a href="<?php echo base_url("index.php/Login/Viewsignup") ?>">Create an account</a> .so from here also i have to remove index.php/Login.After removing this its working fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On some servers, Apache is configured to ignore some or all directives in .htaccess files. This is for security reasons. The AllowOverride directive controls which features will be allowed in .htaccess files. For example AllowOverride None can turn off htaccess files for a folder and its subfolders.

Check your Apache configuration file for which AllowOverride directive is applied to the directory containing your problem htaccess file.

If you’re not sure which configuration file to look in, start with the main Apache configuration file httpd.conf or apache2.conf. If your website is configured in a file included by httpd.conf (e.g. a virtual hosts configuration file), you will need to look in that file. See [Location of httpd.conf on CentOS, Ubuntu, Mac and others](http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/httpd-conf-location-on-centos-ubuntu-mac-and-others) to locate your httpd.conf.

To enable using a .htaccess file, change `AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.`

For example, for a CentOS 5.3 server, I needed to change the AllowOverride setting in the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/virtualhosts.conf.

httpd.conf before:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
```

httpd.conf after:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
```

Be aware that enabling htaccess files has security implications, as htaccess files override your Apache configuration. For example, if your site provides uploads, a hacker could potentially upload a .htaccess file to your server and use it to gain access to your server. There are options to AllowOverride that restrict the directives that will be used from a .htaccess file. See the [documentation for AllowOverride.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

refer http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/htaccess-problems

Comment: Hi,i have check the httpd.conf file in my systems which is at /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf,but they have already have a setting of Allowoverride All then also routing is not working.